# How to create setup/exe in Visual Studio 2013 including a SQL Server database file?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have a desktop application in C# with 4 projects in the solution.

These are:

1. GUI project in C# (WPF)
2. Business Logic Application (console application)
3. Data Access Layer Application (console application)
4. Property Application (console application)

For the database, I have used SQL Server 2012, also I have installed the SQL Server 2012 Express edition on my local system.

Can anyone guide me how to make perfect setup/.exe file for all of above 4 projects existing in 1 solution & database also?

Comment: suggest sqlexpress which has a relatively small size and can be installed in silent mode. and if possible sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org). Using it, you can create an MSI package for your application(s) and a setup bootstrapper that will install your MSI and SQL Server Express.